# SQL Injection on MS Access LogIn

Tags: vba, ms-access, authentication, sql-injection

I am using a MS Access form with the below vba code for my startup page where the user enters a username and password where if its ok, he is forwarded to a dashboard page with relevant content. I was checking to see if the code is SQL Injection proof, and to my horror, it proceeded to log in without a single problem! Could anyone please assist me harden the code to prevent a sql injection attack?

```
If (Me.UserNameTextBox <> "" And Me.passwordtextbox <> "") Then    
        hook = """"
SQLCheckUser = ""
SQLCheckUser = SQLCheckUser & " SELECT Id, UserName, UserCode FROM UserTable"
SQLCheckUser = SQLCheckUser & " WHERE UserName = " & hook & me.UserNameTextBox.value & hook
SQLCheckUser = SQLCheckUser & " AND UserPassword = " & hook & me.passwordtextbox.value & hook
SQLCheckUser = SQLCheckUser & " AND IsInactive=0"

'Create RecordSet
   Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQLCheckUser)

'Go to first record
    rst.MoveLast
    rst.MoveFirst

    If rst.RecordCount <> 1 Then
        MsgBox "Error 2: Please recheck your login details" 'Error 2 Cant find the user or too many users
        rst.Close
           Else
'Good LogIn, load the values of the record into rst   
    ID = rst.Fields("Id")
    UserName = rst.Fields("UserName")
    UserCode = rst.Fields("UserCode")
    IsLoggedIn = True
    rst.Close

     DoCmd.Close
     DoCmd.OpenForm ("Dashboard")

    End If
   Else
MsgBox "Please recheck your login details" ‘ Either UserName or Password has not been entered
End If
```

Comment: The SQL Injection that worked was " or "1"="1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameterized queries are used to protect against SQL Injection vulnerabilities. In your case you would use something like this

```vbs
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "PARAMETERS prmUserName TEXT(255), prmUserPassword TEXT(255);" & _
        "SELECT Id, UserName, UserCode FROM UserTable" & _
        " WHERE UserName = [prmUserName] AND UserPassword = [prmUserPassword] AND IsInactive=0")
qdf!prmUserName = Me.UserNameTextBox.Value
qdf!prmUserPassword = Me.passwordtextbox.Value
Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
```